# Getting errors when setting a wstring to a Hebrew string literal in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, character-encoding, hebrew, string-literals, wstring

I'm using Code Blocks to write a C++ program. I want to put a Hebrew string in an `std::wstring` type, but it isn't working.

If I write this:

```
std::wstring str2("שלום");
```

and compile, it gives me this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<wchar_t>::basic_string(const char [5])'|
```

If I use "L" before the string literal, i.e.

```
std::wstring str2(L"שלום");
```

then it gives the error:

```
error: converting to execution character set: Invalid argument|
```

Comment: If you used the L to indicate that it's a wchat_t, did you include <cstring>?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445388/hebrew-chars-in-c-coutcharchar

Comment: Don't use non-ascii strings in the source of your program, it is not portable, implementation-dependent and a bad practice anyway. Having said that, what encoding is used in your source file?

Comment: i dont know what encoding i use, i use code block and compiler  GNU GCC

Comment: What are the 16 bit values in unicode that correspond to those characters?  What is your runtime encoding of `wchar_t` strings at the point of use?  (I hope unicode!  Utf-32?  Utf-16?  Ucs-2?)  You can probably put escape sequences into the `L""` string and have it work.

Answer (score 3):

Wide string literals have the form `L"peace"`.   The leading L is what tells the compiler it's a `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: when i do that it give me other error:   error: converting to execution character set: Invalid argument|

Comment: @רועינוה For that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190173/c-error-conversion-to-execution-character-set

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

i got it.

i use L before like: str2 (L"שלום");

Set up CodeBlocks editor by clicking Settings then Editor then Encoding settings, and select UTF-8. You probably want to select "As default encoding" and unselect everything else. You won't have to pass -finput-charset to the compiler because UTF-8 is the default

Comment: Don't use iso-8859-8. Use UTF-8 like 99% of the world. Set up CodeBlocks editor by clicking Settings then Editor then Encoding settings, and select UTF-8. You probably want to select "As default encoding" and unselect everything else. You won't have to pass -finput-charset to the compiler because UTF-8 is the default.

Comment: אתה תמיד מוזמן. Also please read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @רועינוה: If you've accepted the suggestion to use UTF-8, please amend your answer accordingly. Recommending the use of iso-8859-8 really is a bad idea.