# Converting to execution character set: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++14, gnu

When compiling I'm getting the error "converting to execution character set: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character" for

```
std::wstring s = L"eéèê";
```

I tried below solutions:

- Tried to use `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` in file
- Tried to compile the single C++ file with the `-finput-charset` flag.
  Example:

  ```
  abc.cpp -finput-charset=iso-8859-1
  ```

  This works when there is single source file but I'm using the **makefile** to compile multiple source files.

How can I set charset flag/utf-8 encoding or set local in **makefile**?

Reference links:

- [C++ error: Conversion to Execution Character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190173/c-error-conversion-to-execution-character-set)
- https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/1849669

Comment: Perhaps the easiest option is to convert all the files to UTF-8? Something like `find . \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.hpp' \) -exec iconv -t UTF8 {} -o {} \;` (but do a dry-run before changing them all)